# it gives null to author when inserting a comment of a post

Tags: php, symfony

i'm new to `symfony`, i want to persist a `comment` of a `post`, when i run `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments` link in `postman`, it return `null` for `author`, it gives `null` for `author` in database.
data that I want to persist:

```
{
    "content":"this is my new comment for this posts",
    "published":"2021-01-09T16:40:21+00:00",
    "post":"/api/posts/728"
}
```

**AuthorSubscriber.php**

```
public function getUserFromToken(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if(($entity instanceof Post || $entity instanceof Comment) && $method == Request::METHOD_POST) {
            
            $author = $this->myToken->getToken()->getUser();
            $entity->setAuthor($author);
        } 
    }
```

**Post.php**

```
private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="post")
     * @ApiSubresource()
     */
```

**Comment.php**

```
private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
```

Comment: Are you doing a flush someplace after the listener is called? I assume you have already verified that setAuthor is indeed being called.  I'd also be a bit skeptical that myToken is actually valid because of the order in which subscribers are created.  Typically you would use something like $this->security->getUser().

Comment: @Cerad thx for u answer ,`setAuthor` exists in `Post.php` and `Comment.php` but i dont know where i will add `$this->security->getUser();`

Comment: Okay.  So you are trying to modify someone else's code?  Probably best to ask them.  If not then take a look at the security docs.